# Getting list of WiFi Profiles with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, wifi

I am trying to collect a list of the installed WiFi profiles. I have used a batch for this which works perfectly. I am trying to make it work with python to generate the networks into a list for use with other functions. What I have in Python script right now is:

`subprocess.call(["for", "/f", "\"tokens=2*delims=:\"", "%a", "in", "(', "netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles')", "do", "(if", "\"%a\"", "neq", "\"\"", "echo(%a)"])`

I used print() to make sure it was going into cmd correctly, which it was, and it gave me:

```
for /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %a in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do (if "%a" neq "" echo(%a)
```

The previous batch file was:

```
@echo off
set "flag="
(for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do (
    if "%%a"=="User profiles" set flag=true
    if defined flag if "%%~b" neq "" (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ("%%~b") do echo(%%c
    )
))>out.txt
type out.txt
```

The error I receive is:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1702, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:\Users\Documents\Test.py", line 83, in WirelessFiltering
> subprocess.call(["for", "/f", ""tokens=2*delims=:"", "%a", "in", "('netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles')", "do", "(if", ""%a"", "neq", """", "echo(%a)"])
> File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 304, in call
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
> File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)
> File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
> startupinfo)
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try at this, let me know if it gives you the desired result please.

```
import subprocess

a = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
a = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in a if "All User Profile" in i]
for i in a:
    results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile']).split('\n')
    try:
        print ("{}".format(i, results[0]))
    except IndexError:
        print format(i)
```

It does pretty much the same as your batch file did, only difference, here I specifically get only the lines containing `All User Profiles` It will still get the profiles without it, but obviously unwanted lines as well.

As you mentioned in a comment that you wanted to do this for remote machines, you would need to incorporate the remote switch with domain credentials.. Something like:

```
subprocess.check_output(['netsh', '-r', 'device', '-u ', 'domain\user', '-p', 'password', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']
```

Comment: in `data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')` if I exclude the `"wlan"` it doesn't give error but if I include it , it gives error : (  want to ask what is the `"wlan"` means and how can I solve this ?

Comment: @Paullam  it is wireless lan. What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm using Windows ; Python 3.8 ; when I run `data = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n")` it raises the error : `raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: after following [this article](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-wifi-network-not-showing-up-on-computer/) 's method  2 , the error is gone but seems like sth not right  output : `['There is no wireless interface on the system.\r', '']`